# Unzip all .zip archives in a directory

Tags: c#, zip, system.io.compression

I am struggling to configure a script to unzip all .zip archives in a directory and place the extracted files into a different directory.   I am wanting to schedule this script to run on a schedule to handle incoming .zip archives.

For each .zip file in the source directory, I need it to extract those files to the destination, then repeat until all .zip files have been processed.

Here is my horrible attempt.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

namespace Unzipper
{
class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startPath = @"C:\zipdirectory\";

        foreach(String file in Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.zip", SearchOptions.AllDirectories)){allFiles.Add(file);

        string zipPath = @"(output from above??)

        string extractPath = @"C:\unzipdirectory\";

        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having?

Comment: Why not extract in your foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you get all `.zip` file in the `startPath`

For each path, unzip it to a new folder created by a combination like `C:\unzipdirectory\<zip_file_name_without_extension_zip>`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string startPath = @"C:\zipdirectory\";
        string extractPath = @"C:\unzipdirectory\";
        Directory.GetFiles(startPath, "*.zip", SearchOptions.AllDirectories).ToList()
            .ForEach(zipFilePath => {
                var extractPathForCurrentZip = Path.Combine(extractPath, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(zipFilePath));
                if(!Directory.Exists(extractPathForCurrentZip))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(extractPathForCurrentZip);
                }
                ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipFilePath, extractPathForCurrentZip);
        });
    }
```

Comment: what if my zip file contains another .zip file inside of it? I tried your solution but it does not extract the .zip file inside of it.